# Create bend points in links with drag and drop using D3 or javascript

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I have graph consisting of various node/edges made using D3 [not using D3 force] which have node dragging feature.
I am trying to implement a functionality where a user can click on any point on a link and drag to random point, such that it created a bend point in that edge to the dragged point between source and target node.

I have the link made using svg path little similar to the following sample [Example](https://bl.ocks.org/dimitardanailov/6f0a451d4457b9fa7bf6e0dddcd0f468), given below which have bend points made using data of some array which I am calculating according to the positions of source and target nodes in original code:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 400;
var height = 400;

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg');
svg.attr('width', width);
svg.attr('height', height);

//This is the accessor function we talked about above
var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
  .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
  .interpolate('linear');

//The data for our line
var lineData = [ 
  { "x": 1,   "y": 5},  
  { "x": 60,  "y": 30},
  { "x": 100, "y": 60}
];
  
//The line SVG Path we draw
var lineGraph = svg.append("path")
  .attr("d", lineFunction(lineData))
  .attr("stroke", "blue")
  .attr("stroke-width", 2)
  .attr("fill", "none");
</script>
```

I need help in logic where I can just click on any point on the link and drag & create new bend points in the link.

Comment: Are you committed to v3?

Comment: Yes, I am. But is there a simple solution with V4?

Comment: No, it's just because I don't like writing answers using v3.

Comment: Ok, Please provide your V4 solution, looks like I must have to upgrade now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a solution for the edge dragging problem [Here](http://bl.ocks.org/vishalash/247014d87c0f1971ae8b9a6df290a02f). Although a better solution is welcome.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
   .link {
   stroke: #aaa;
   }
   .node text {
   stroke:#333;
   cursos:pointer;
   }
   .node circle{
   stroke:#fff;
   stroke-width:3px;
   fill:#555;
   }
</style>
<body>
<p id="first"><p>
<p id="second"><p>

   <script>
      
      var data = {
        "nodes":[
        {"id":"node1","x":100,"y":400},
        {"id":"node2","x":500,"y":200},
        {"id":"node3","x":600,"y":120},
        {"id":"node4","x":900,"y":400}
       ],
       "links":[
        {"source":"node2","target":"node1","weight":1,"id":"abc"},
        {"source":"node3","target":"node4","weight":3,"id":"xyz"}
       ]
      }
   

   
      var width = 1200,
          height = 500
      var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
          .attr("width", width)
          .attr("height", height);
      d3.json("", function(json) {
      json = data;
   

       
        var nodes = svg.selectAll(".node")
            .data(json.nodes)
          .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "node");
            
        nodes.append("rect")
            .attr("width","5").attr("height","5").attr("x",function(d){return d.x}).attr("y",function(d){return d.y});
         
        nodes.append("text")
            .attr("dx", 12)
            .attr("dy", ".35em").attr("x",function(d){return d.x}).attr("y",function(d){return d.y}) 
            .text(function(d) { return d.id });
         
         var LinkCurve = "linear";
         
         var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
              .x(function(d) {
                  return d.a;
              })
              .y(function(d) {
                  return d.b;
              })
              .interpolate(LinkCurve);
     
////////////////////////////////////Edge Drag//////////////////////////////
          var EdgeDrag = d3.behavior.drag()
              .on("dragstart", dragstartedEdge)
              .on("drag", draggedEdge)
              .on("dragend", dragEndedEdge);
          var firstPointBool = true;
          var firstDragX = 0;
          var firstDragY = 0;
          var bendPointAddPos = 0;
          function dragstartedEdge() {
              
              d3.selectAll(".linkInTopology").classed("selectedLink", false).style("stroke", "blue");
        d3.select(this).classed("selectedLink", true);
              
              firstPointBool = true;
              firstDragX = 0;
              firstDragY = 0;
              bendPointAddPos = 0;
          }
    
          var controlPointsArrLinkDrag = [];
          var dragEdgeBool = false;
          function draggedEdge(d) {
              dragEdgeBool = true;
              d3.selectAll(".selectedLink").attr("d", function(l) {
                  if (firstPointBool) {
                      firstDragX = d3.event.x;
                      firstDragY = d3.event.y;
                      for (i = 0; i < l.controlPoints.length; i += 2) {
                          var firstAngle = Math.abs((l.controlPoints[i + 1] - firstDragY) / (l.controlPoints[i] - firstDragX));
                          var secondAngle = Math.abs((firstDragY - l.controlPoints[i + 3]) / (firstDragX - l.controlPoints[i + 2]));
                          if (firstAngle.toFixed(1) == secondAngle.toFixed(1) && Math.max(l.controlPoints[i], l.controlPoints[i + 2]) >= firstDragX && Math.min(l.controlPoints[i], l.controlPoints[i + 2]) <= firstDragX) {
                              bendPointAddPos = i + 2;
         d3.selectAll(".selectedLink").style("stroke", "red");
                          }
                      }
                  }
                  var sourceNode = json.nodes.filter(function(d, i) {
                      return d.id == l.source
                  })[0];
                  var targetNode = json.nodes.filter(function(d, i) {
                      return d.id == l.target
                  })[0];
                  // Fetch the initial edge bend points in controlPointsArrLinkDrag array
                  lineData.length = 0;
                  controlPointsArrLinkDrag.length = 0;
                  l.controlPoints.forEach(function(d) {
                      controlPointsArrLinkDrag.push(d);
                  })
                  if (bendPointAddPos != 0) {
                      controlPointsArrLinkDrag.splice(bendPointAddPos, 0, d3.event.x);
                      controlPointsArrLinkDrag.splice(bendPointAddPos + 1, 0, d3.event.y);
                  }
                  for (i = 0; i < controlPointsArrLinkDrag.length; i += 2) {
                      lineData.push({
                          "a": controlPointsArrLinkDrag[i],
                          "b": controlPointsArrLinkDrag[i + 1]
                      });
                  }
                  ///////
                  return lineFunction(lineData)
              })
              firstPointBool = false;
          }
          function dragEndedEdge() {
              if (dragEdgeBool) {
                  d3.selectAll(".selectedLink").attr("d", function(l) {
                      lineData.length = 0;
                      for (i = 0; i < controlPointsArrLinkDrag.length; i += 2) {
                          lineData.push({
                              "a": controlPointsArrLinkDrag[i],
                              "b": controlPointsArrLinkDrag[i + 1]
                          });
                      }
                      l.controlPoints.length = 0;
                      l.controlPoints = controlPointsArrLinkDrag.slice();
                      return lineFunction(lineData)
                  })
              }
     json.links.forEach(function(d,i){
     if(i == 0){
    d3.select("#first").text("bend-points of link between node1-node2: [" + d.controlPoints + "]")
      }
      else{
    d3.select("#second").text("bend-points of link between node3-node4: [" + d.controlPoints + "]")
      }
     })
                 
          }
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
          //The data for our line
          var lineData = [];
         
         function setupPolyLinks() {
              
              d3.selectAll(".linkInTopology").remove();
              
              edges = svg.selectAll("linkInTopology")
                  .data(json.links)
                  .enter()
                  .insert("path", ".node")
                  .attr("class", "linkInTopology").attr("id", function(l) {
                      return l.id;
                  }).attr("source", function(l) {
                      return l.source;
                  }).attr("target", function(l) {
                      return l.target;
                  }).attr("d", function(l) {
                          lineData.length = 0;
                          controlPointsArr = [];
                          var sourceNode = json.nodes.filter(function(d, i) {
                              return d.id == l.source
                          })[0];
                          var targetNode = json.nodes.filter(function(d, i) {
                              return d.id == l.target
                          })[0];
                         
                              lineData.push({
                                  "a": sourceNode.x ,
                                  "b": sourceNode.y
                              });
                              controlPointsArr.push(sourceNode.x);
                              controlPointsArr.push(sourceNode.y);
                          
                          lineData.push({
                              "a": targetNode.x ,
                              "b": targetNode.y
                          });
                          controlPointsArr.push(targetNode.x);
                          controlPointsArr.push(targetNode.y);
                          l.controlPoints = [];
                          for (i = 0; i < controlPointsArr.length; i++) {
                              l.controlPoints.push(controlPointsArr[i]);
                          }
                          return lineFunction(lineData)
                      
                  }).style("stroke-width", "5").attr("stroke", "blue").attr("fill", "none").call(EdgeDrag);
      }
      setupPolyLinks();
    json.links.forEach(function(d,i){
     if(i == 0){
    d3.select("#first").text("bend-points of link between node1-node2: [" + d.controlPoints + "]")
      }
      else{
    d3.select("#second").text("bend-points of link between node3-node4: [" + d.controlPoints + "]")
      }
     })
         
      })
   </script>
```